# Choice of constant in 1st order linear equation not matter

Tags: calculus

I just want to clear some confusion if someone help me to solve my problem. I want to ask that, "Why the choice of constant of integration in the integrating factor like $e^{\int P(x)\, dx}$, does not matter while solving a 1st order linear differential equation."

Comment: Adding of constant $C$ multiply solution by $e^C$; equation is linear; so, it chnges anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$e^{f(x)+C}=e^{f(x)}\cdot e^C,$$

including a constant of integration would amount to multiplying the entire equation through by a constant, which would end up canceling later anyway.